# Making Kibana connect to an elasticsearch server which is secured by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, elasticsearch, kibana

i have a public-facing elasticsearch server and have secured access to it using htaccess. The issue is that Kibana is unable to connect to elasticsearch now.

Tried the following in Kibana's config.js, but it fails-

```
elasticsearch: "https://username:password@elasticsearch.example.com",
```

i get the red bar in Kibana interface saying-

> "Please ensure that elasticsearch is reachable from your system."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the service elasticsearch is running

```
service elasticsearch status
```

You can restart the service by

```
service elasticsearch restart
```

You can view the log file of elasticsearch basically at following location

```
/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
```

By default elasticsearch listen on port 9200. Check if you have mentioned the port.